# vim - fixed width tabs

Tags: vim

```
<Tab>
<Space><Tab>
```

In this case the first tab has a width of tabstop characters but the second has the width of tabstop-1 characters. How do I make all tabs always be tabstop characters wide?

Answer (score 2):

The defining characteristic of tabstops is that they "snap" to certain positions (in Vim, multiples of the `'tabstop'` setting). What you want is something different, and cannot be achieved (in any editor I know) with the `\t` = `<Tab>` = ASCII 0x09 character.

What you can do is define a mapping that inserts `'tabstop'` amount of spaces when you press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key:

```
:inoremap <expr> <Tab> repeat(' ', &tabstop)
```

(Of course, you can also choose another key for this, or make this buffer-local with `<buffer>`.)

Comment: tabstop spaces is not one tab.

Comment: @HristoVenev: My answer explains why a physical tab won't behave the way you want; best you can do is expand it to spaces. Does your comment mean that you're not happy about that?!

Comment: How do I make tabs look like a fixed number of spaces but actually be tabs?

Comment: **You can't** (without modifying and re-compiling Vim itself).

Comment: (Well with `:set tabstop=1`, every tab will have a width of 1, but that won't work for any other value.)

Comment: Is there whitespace character != 0x20 that has a fixed width != 1?

Comment: You're tenacious! I can only think of U+3000 IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE, which is double-width. Enter with `<C-V>u3000`, or `<C-K>IS`.